# Fiddler 2 won't launch

Tags: fiddler

I try to start fiddler 2 and I get this message box:

> Fiddler 2 startup aborted
>   Fiddler appears to be running in this users account
>   Maybe in a terminals services session

I loaded fiddler onto another machine on our wireless network and it displays the same message. How do I fix this so I can run fiddler normally?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the problem with the latest version? https://www.fiddler2.com/dl/fiddler2alphasetup.exe